# Playing card object

Tags: python, object-oriented, playing-cards

I am writing this class to eventually create a playing card game (Spades) and also to utilize the object oriented paradigm. This was my attempt to model a card as an object. Each card has a suit and a rank that have each been given a specific weight that can be modified to fit the needs of the game. I have had several thoughts on how to implement this code differently, I thought about collapsing the weight system I had into a 1 - to 52 type system, or defining a dictionary where all cards assigned a value etc. However I decided to keep what I currently have as I feel this may yield greater flexibility to be expanded across several games. Last note, I decided to employ the Joker identity as a catch for cards that fall outside the expected input.

```
class Card(object):
    """Models a playing card, each Card object will have a suit, rank, and weight associated with each.

    possible_suits -- List of possible suits a card object can have
    possible_ranks -- List of possible ranks a card object can have
    Suit and rank weights are initialized by position in list.
    If card parameters are outside of expected values, card becomes joker with zero weight
    """

    possible_suits = ["Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades"]
    possible_ranks = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K", "A"]

    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        if suit in Card.possible_suits and rank in Card.possible_ranks:
            self.suit = suit
            self.rank = rank
            self.suit_weight = Card.possible_suits.index(suit)
            self.rank_weight = Card.possible_ranks.index(rank)
        else:
            self.suit = "Joker"
            self.rank = "J"
            self.suit_weight = 0
            self.rank_weight = 0

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns abbreviated name of card

        Example: str(Card('Spades', 'A') outputs 'AS'
        """
        return str(self.rank) + self.suit[0]

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """Return True if cards are equal by suit and rank weight"""
        return self.suit_weight == other.suit_weight and self.rank_weight == other.rank_weight

    def __gt__(self, other):
        """Returns true if first card is greater than second card by weight"""
        if self.suit_weight > other.suit_weight:
            return True
        if self.suit_weight == other.suit_weight:
            if self.rank_weight > other.rank_weight:
                return True
        return False

    def modify_weight(self, new_suit_weight = None, new_rank_weight = None):
        """Modifies weight of card object"""
        if new_suit_weight:
            self.suit_weight = new_suit_weight
        if new_rank_weight:
            self.rank_weight = new_rank_weight

    def get_suit(self):
        return self.suit

    def get_rank(self):
        return self.rank

    def get_suit_weight(self):
        return self.suit_weight

    def get_rank_weight(self):
        return self.rank_weight
```